# Basic_ncsa_auth.exe is not running. Squid Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, squid

After installing squid proxy in server 2016 windows, squid proxy process basic_ncsa_auth.exe is not running, because of this squid proxy is not working.

Solution provided in below links:-
http://xaviertidus.com/linux/could-not-determine-this-machines-public-hostname-please-configure-one-or-set-visible_hostname-squid/

http://squid-web-proxy-cache.1019090.n4.nabble.com/WARNING-Could-not-determine-this-machines-public-hostname-Please-configure-one-or-set-visible-hostna-td4663074.html

https://serverfault.com/questions/414201/config-squid-for-windows-with-basic-authorization-but-squid-still-denied-access

https://gist.github.com/yvanin/ef831720112c1f6ee8c3

but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding following lines in squid.conf file it starts running.

auth_param basic program C:\Squid\lib\squid\basic_ncsa_auth.exe C:\Squid\etc.htpasswd
acl ncsa_users proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow ncsa_users
auth_param basic children 5 startup=5 idle=1

here in last line 5 stands for number of processes that can be changed to any number.